# Is $(0, 1)$ a compact open set?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I am working off of the following definition of compactness:

> We say that $\mathcal{U}$ is a *cover* of $X$ if every point of $X$ is in some $U_{\lambda}$, or in other words:
> $$
> X \subset \bigcup_{\lambda \in \Lambda} U_{\lambda}.
> $$
> We say that the collection $\mathcal{U}$ is an *open cover* if each $U_{\lambda}$ is open.
> $X$ is then **compact** if for every open cover $\mathcal{U}$ of $X$, there exists a finite subset $\mathcal{U}' \subset \mathcal{U}$ that is also an open cover.

Then, I'm asked to prove that every compact set is closed.
However, since an open set $(0, 1) = \{x \mid 0 < x < 1\}$ is covered by $\mathcal{U} = \{(0, 1)\}$, which has a finite subset $\mathcal{U}' = \mathcal{U}$ which also covers $(0, 1)$, shouldn't it be a compact set?

Comment: No, you would need to show *every* open cover has a finite subcover (which is not so).

Comment: @DavidMitra Thank you for a quick response, but could you give me an example of such a cover without a finite subcover?

Comment: Sets of the form $(1/n, 1-1/n)$.

Comment: It is important to notice that *every* in there.  Of course there always is a finite cover by open sets (one set: the whole space), so without that  *every* we get an uninteresting definition.